# Generating a kubeconfig for access to an Amazon EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubeconfig

Given a scenario where I have two Kubernetes clusters, one hosted on AWS EKS and the other on another cloud provider, I would like to manage the EKS cluster from the other cloud provider. What's the easiest way to authenticate such that I can do this?

Would it be reasonable to generate a kubeconfig, where I embed the result from `aws get-token` (or something like that) to the cluster on the other cloud provider? Or are these tokens not persistent?

Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the most correct  is the way described in [Create a kubeconfig for Amazon EKS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-kubeconfig.html)

yes, you create `kubeconfig` with `aws eks get-token` and later add newly created config to KUBECONFIG environment variable , eg

```
export KUBECONFIG=$KUBECONFIG:~/.kube/config-aws
```

or you can add it to `.bash_profile` for your convenience

```
echo 'export KUBECONFIG=$KUBECONFIG:~/.kube/config-aws' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

For detailed steps please refer to provided url.

Comment: Taken from the link you provide, this worked for me: `aws eks update-kubeconfig --region <your-region> --name <your cluster name>`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a linux platform on the second cloud provider, you can use the following command for generating kube config file:

`aws eks update-kubeconfig --region <region-code> --name <cluster-name>`

You can change the file using `--kubeconfig` flag.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-kubeconfig.html

Answer (score 0):

I had this use case where I needed to work with multi-cloud providers.

So I created [kubech](https://github.com/aabouzaid/kubech) to deal with that situation and manage multiple clusters simultaneously.